# C# - internal static readonly is null on access

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
internal class FakeInvitationsRepository : InvitationsRepository
{
    internal readonly static Dictionary<Guid, InvitationDbEntity> Data = new Dictionary<Guid, InvitationDbEntity>()
    {
        { ...
```

Here's a screen-shot, for what its worth:

[image: Screen shot of real code]

It's just some in-memory fake data, 3 items in all. The class lives inside an ASP.NET WebAPI project, not in a test DLL but in the WebAPI DLL for the time being.

An API call comes in and hits a breakpoint in the controller action where it tries to consume this fake data directly, no IoC yet or anything clever.

But the field `Data` is null. It's causing a null ref exception at runtime.

[image: Screen show showing null]

The C# language spec says:

> If a static constructor (Section 10.11) exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to the first use of a static field of that class.

What's happening here such that the field is not initialized prior to first-use?

Note: A colleague has quickly sanity checked and is also bemused. `Data` is only ever set, never nulled by my code (its readonly afterall).

Edit

Here's the callstack of just my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace t = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
{   at Company.Product.WebAPI.Controllers.RenamedController.<GetInvitations>d__14.MoveNext()
   at Company.Product.WebAPI.Controllers.RenamedController.GetInvitations(Guid id)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Company.WebAPI.Product.Areas.RouteDebugger.InspectActionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Company.WebAPI.Product.Areas.RouteDebugger.InspectHandler.<>n__FabricatedMethod12(HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken )
   at Company.WebAPI.Product.Areas.RouteDebugger.InspectHandler.<SendAsync>d__e.MoveNext()
   at Company.WebAPI.Product.Areas.RouteDebugger.InspectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
    FrameCount: 84
    frames: {System.Diagnostics.StackFrame[87]}
    m_iMethodsToSkip: 3
    m_iNumOfFrames: 84
```

---

### **Answer**

I can't answer because the question was put on hold. Debatable.

Thanks to MStodd. The answer is silly and straight-forward, but somewhat surprising; I don't recall having ever seen this in 11 years of .NET programming.

The `Data` field was not yet initialized.

Placing a breakpoint in the initializer, the entire block goes red, showed that it was called on the next step.

The `NullReferenceException` was a red-herring and due to `this.Invitations` being null.

Of course, I was expecting the field to be initialized by the time that line is stopped at, I just didn't expect it to happen so late, and so assumed the `null` was causing my runtime exception.

There you go.

Comment: What does the stack trace look like? My guess is that you're seeing this *while* initializing the type, in some recursive initializer. If you could post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, I'm sure we could sort it out...

Comment: That's a good shout, Jon. I'll paste the call stack without any `System.*` calls, so just my code.

Comment: Is it possible something deeper in Data is null and the readout in the IDE just isn't showing you it?

Comment: I am seeing a lambda method call in the call stack. Could it be possible to be a closure issue ? From what i see .Invitations property is evaluated! (GetInvitations (int id)) so Data is NOT null but we are inside "Select". I can put a bet that Invitations is NULL

Comment: Could you please add relevant code that you use to initialize a static field ? It looks like problem lay not with the field itself but with how it's being initialized.

Comment: @GeorgeLica I think that's in the WebAPI framework itself. The line of code hitting the null ref is the very first line of a controller action.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have to leave the office but I'll look with fresh eyes tomorrow and see if I can repro it in a demo WebAPI app (probably not ;)).

Comment: @Luke Puplett From what I know, the "toppest" thing on a call stack is the thing that was OK before exception was thrown. So in our case, it's the Company.Product.WebAPI.Controllers.RenamedController.<GetInvitations>d__14.MoveNext(). the d__14 is FOR SURE the enumerator type that was generated at compile time for our .Invitations property.

Comment: @GeorgeLica That's just the MS implementation of the `async Task<ActionResult>` -- its an asynchronous API action.

Comment: Can you step through your invitations getter?

Comment: @Luke Puplett ... i saw that everything goes executed under a "Task" but that does not have anything to do with what I am seing on the call stack. Let's think logically: what is most probable? Microsoft got wrong and there is a bug in the CLR OR there is something lurking (like what i said).

Comment: @Luke Puplett : put a breakpoint in ".Invitations" property getter and check if it gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

From your call stack i can deduce that the Invitations property is evaluated(in the Select body). Being the last one on the call stack i can deduce that the null reference raises due to the fact that Invitations is NULL!). I suppose that Data = NULL is NOT related to the call stack at all! but rather it is a debugger issue.